# Click a dropdown search result item at random location in the dropdown result python selenium library

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying my head around to select the searched elements in the screenshot below. I tried the below methods none of them seems to be able to find the dropdown searched results elements.

[image]
Sharing the corresponding source code of the dropdown result below based on inspecting the result.

[image]

Following methods I have tried so far using `selenium` python library.

```
    span_class="Roboto--ezzN4 text-5--NzQT7"
    tag_name = "aria-label"
    drop_down_tag_result = driver.find_element(by="class name", value=span_class)
    drop_down_tag_result = driver.find_element(by="tag name", value=tag_name)    
    
    drop_down_result = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//div[text()="+"'"+brand_name+"'"+"]")
    drop_down_result.click()
```

All of above three methods can't locate the element and getting similar error below.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Roboto--ezzN4 text-5--NzQT7"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.109);
```

Can anyone help me guide in the right direction? I am new to selenium.

Comment: This usually happens when the element you are trying to find is not present on the web page or is not visible at the time of the search. Use explicit waits to ensure that the element is present and visible before you try to interact with it. 
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Roboto--ezzN4.text-5--NzQT7')))


element.click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might possibility of synchronization issue. use explicit wait before interacting the element with expected condition see the example here --> [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Please change the `xpath` to identify the element uniquely.

```
drop_down_result = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//span[text()='" + brand_name + "']")
```

or

```
drop_down_result = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="//div[@aria-label='" + brand_name + "']")
```